# Store a cell's value to a new row in a specific column every time that cell changes

Tags: vba, excel, row

In my nonworking example I use the cell C5 as the cell to enter a value. 
What I am trying to do is: Every time a new value is entered into the cell C5, that value should be stored in the column A starting from A1 and onwards.

*(For example: I enter number 1.205 - it gets stored in A1, then I enter number 1.572 - it gets stored in A2, and so on).*

I know that my method is probably far from correct, so any help is appreciated. I have tried a few different ways to achieve this, but I can't get it to work, maximum I have achieved is being able to store up until the 2nd row of column A.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim SourceCell As Range
    Dim CheckCell As Range
    Dim I As Integer

    I = 1
    Set SourceCell = Range("C5")
    Set CheckCell = Range("A" & I)

    If IsEmpty(CheckCell) Then
        CheckCell.Value = SourceCell         
    ElseIf Not IsEmpty(CheckCell) Then
        I = I + 1
        Set CheckCell = Range("A" & I)
        CheckCell.Value = SourceCell   
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to check if the changed cell is C5 and if so then find the last used cell in column A and write the value below:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$C$5" Then 'check if changed cell is C5
        Dim lRow As Long
        lRow = Range("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'find last used row in column A

        Application.EnableEvents = False 'prevent triggering another change event
        Cells(lRow + 1, "A").Value = Target.Value 'write value in column A
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that I added a `Application.EnableEvents = False` to prevent triggering another `Change` event by adding the value to column A.

*Note: I recommend to [always use `Long` instead of `Integer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26409520/3219613) especially when using it for row counting. Excel has more rows than Integer can handle.*

Comment: That looks great!

Comment: @Jeeped of course you are correct it was too early :( corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim tgt As Range
    Set tgt = Range("C5")
    If Intersect(Target, tgt) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Cells(LastRow, 1) = Target.Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True    

End Sub

Function LastRow(Optional ByVal ws As Worksheet = ActiveSheet, Optional ByVal col As Variant = "A") As Long
    With ws
        LastRow = .Cells(.rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function
```